# NPM not installing node module

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an angular project that comes with a `package.json` file and all the dependencies listed within, but each time I run "npm install", in the terminal, the packages appear to be downloading properly and a node module folder is created in my root folder, but at a certain stage the installation stops without an error message and the generated node module folder disappear from my project. please what do I do?

Comment: What is the error message? Please provide more details also take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you get if you run it in verbose? Append the --loglevel verbose argument to the command

Comment: @VítorFrança there are no error or success messages displayed, the process just stops.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your situation, somehow this may not fitable for you.
But I suggest re-install node.js to make sure `npm install` work correctly.
This link will help to find what version of node.js for you, based on you angular version.
[Compatibility list for Angular/Angular-CLI and Node.js](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3/)

Also, It would be good to manage node.js via NVM(Node Version Manager).